# TeamCity - MSBuild unable to locate NuGet references

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, nuget

Attempting to build a C# project which has numerous references to assemblies in NuGet packages fails in TeamCity but works fine in Visual Studio.

Found in the log;

```
For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".

[13:48:15][ResolveAssemblyReference]         
Considered "..\packages\AspNetMvc.4.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll", but it didn't exist.
```

The reference in the project file is;

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\AspNetMvc.4.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Any ideas? It seems like it's not starting from the correct directory so can't resolve "../packages" which exists one level above the .csproj file.

Comment: It appears to be an MSBuild issue, I've just run it from the command line and it cannot locate assemblies with a <HintPath> of ..\packages\etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had restructured my projects since installing the NuGet packages so even though '../packages' was correct for the main project, it wasn't for the other projects which had been moved.

Uninstalling and re-installing the NuGet packages writes the paths correctly or more straightforward, doing a find and replace on the paths in each .csproj file.

Answer (score 11):

I know this has been answered, but maybe someone else has had the same problem I did.

My hint paths in my project file were incorrectly pointing to packages and changing it to ..packages fixed it for me.

So changing it from this:

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
  <HintPath>packages\Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.5\lib\net40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

To this:

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.5\lib\net40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding at this point is based on the information here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-20525

But I am just diving into both TeamCity and NuGet at the same time (coming from CruiseControl.NET)

So what I did for the time being is to add a "NuGet Installer" build step before my vs.net solution build step and everything worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to add the packages directory to source control or enable nuget to automatically download packages (its a feature in the right click menu of nuget 1.6)

See http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Comment: The package folder is under source control and present in TC's working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for resurrecting this old post, but in addition to the above excellent points (Tjaart, SeeNoWeevil, Luke), you might also want to check the property `CopyLocal=true` for the references that you nuget'ed down.

For myself, this has often been the one tiny oversight that leads to exactly the error that the OP was mentioning.

Comment: If `CopyLocal=true` is the correct setup, then how did it become `false`?

Comment: That is truly a mystery to me as well, but since nugets are usually not GAC'd, you won't get too far without copylocal=true. Maybe due to a bad nuget pack?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem:
When I ran the "dotnet restore" command and tried to compile the project with msbuild I got the same error present in this thread.
My solution was to replace the "dotnet restore -f" command with "nuget restore"

PS: The path for nuget command in Mac is: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/nuget

Answer (score -1):

You can highlight the file in Solution Explorer and got to Properties, and verify that `Copy to Output Directory` is set to `True`

Comment: That's purely for deployment though right? TC can't actually build the project because MSBuild can't access the referenced assemblies during compilation (not in the GAC)

Comment: @thecapsaicinkid - AFAIK it happens during the build.

Answer (score -1):

### Ensure that the .dll and .pdb files are included in source control (or have been downloaded).

For TFS (not TeamCity), by default, `.pdb` files and `.dll` files are excluded. So double-check that all files for each package sub-directory have been included, not just the nuget `.xml` file.

*Background: I came to this question with the same thought as some other posters - that the relative reference in the `.csproj` file might be incorrect. After using a path in the .csproj file to ensure that the reference was absolute with regards to the project...
      `<HintPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\.nuget\packages\Common.Logging.Core.3.0.0\lib\net40\Common.Logging.Core.dll</HintPath>`
..only to get the same error, I double-checked that the required files existed. I also did an MSBuild build on my local machine (as opposed to Visual Studio build), and it worked. Further investigation on the build server revealed that the specified files did not exist, even though the directory, and .nuget package `.xml` files did.*

Comment: In a general sense, it is not recommended to check-in build artifacts like DLLs/PDBs.

Comment: @Matt In general, I agree. However NuGet packages are essentially 3rd-party dependencies that are, based on the NuGet structure, part of the references required to build a project. The argument for including these in source control is that for many NuGet packages, source is not provided, and thus these binaries form external dependencies that are necessary to build the code, and thus should be kept with the code. (Consider the case when the internet is not available, without the NuGet packages, the code would be unbuildable).